# Can't install Inkscape on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: kde, 19.04, plasma-5, inkscape, poppler

I'm trying to install InkScape on Ubuntu 19.04 from Discover (KDE plasma store), but it shows error:

```
Dependencies resolution failed
```

I tried installing it from PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:inkscape.dev/stable
sudo apt install inkscape -y
```

but it still shows dependencies unmet. This package or dependency is unmet.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
inkscape : Depends: libpoppler82 (>= 0.71.0) but it is not installable
            Recommends: python-uniconvertor but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How to install it, I can't find any solution.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Added some useful information from your [posting at stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56663347/cant-install-inkscape-on-ubuntu-19-04) ... please next time avoid posting on multiple SE sites, rather choose the one where your question is on-topic (here it is!).

Comment: Okay, well can you help me with this?

Comment: Thank you!! It worked! I was trying to install this from morning but every solution said to add that ppa and it only wasted my time. Thank you again. You're life saver.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both the [`disco` repositories](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/disco/+source/inkscape) and the [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~inkscape.dev/+archive/ubuntu/stable) currently provide version 0.92.4.
So you don't need the ppa, [remove it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed):

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:inkscape.dev/stable
```

then update your repositories:

```
sudo apt update
```

and to fix some potential dependency issues (might not be needed, but it's always safe to run):

```
sudo apt install -f
```

then install inkscape:

```
sudo apt install inkscape
```

Comment: In Ubuntu 22.04 I had to use the PPA to get it working.